# On what day was the air created?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-bereishit

Since we're back to Bereyshis, I was wondering,
the air is not mentioned in the Torah, besides the wind, of course.
THe Hebrew "אויר" is actually the Greek "aero"
as they eventually realized that there's air even without the wind.

When our sages accepted the idea,
what day of the Creation did they assign it to?

Comment: In both Hebrew (*ruach*) and Greek (*pnoe*, *pneuma*), wind and breath are nearly synonymous, being expressed by similar or identical terms. Since all living beings breathe, it cannot have been later than the fifth day; most likely, the second, wherein the waters above, signifying atmospheric moisture, were separated from the waters below, representing the lakes, seas, and oceans. The first three days of creation basically correspond to the four classical elements, in increasing order of density, and the other three to their respective inhabitants.

Comment: The Hebrew word for [heaven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaven_in_Judaism) is dual, the two heavens being the air and the sky, as it says in scripture: the birds of heaven, and the stars of heaven.